# error log is going to the wrong location, WP_DEBUG_LOG is ignored

Tags: debug, wp-debug, logging

My WordPress error log is going to `/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log`.  That's not where I want it. In fact, it took me too long to figure that out. (I'm new to WP and PHP).

I've tried to redirect it with the following in my `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/wp-errors.log' ); 
error_log("hello from wp-config\n");
```

but it has no effect.  This code is placed before/above the  "stop editing" warning. I've tried other log file locations like /tmp, still,  my WP_DEBUG_LOG setting is ignored.  I do receive the "hello" message that I wrote - it's just in the wrong file.

I can successfully write to other locations using the form of error_log() that takes a path, like error_log('hello', 3, '/tmp/mylog.log').

ini_get('error_log') returns the path that is being used.

My php.ini does not specify a log location.

It's not a file permissions problem.

I'm self-hosting WP 5.5.1 on AWS Linux 2 (like Centos 7), with PHP 7.2.24

Thoughts?

Update Oct 12:
I learned that php-fpm is capturing the output, and that php-fpm can be configured to change this behavior.  I was not able to get what I want, and I'm not motivated to continue this effort, but others with the same problem may want to look at these settings in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

```
php_flag[display_errors] = ?? 
catch_workers_output = ??
php_admin_value[error_log] = ??
```

see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677493/php-fpm-doesnt-write-to-error-log

Comment: You wouldn't be able to error_log() immediately after the define() like that in wp-config: the error path isn't copied into `ini_set( 'error_log', ... )` until a few dozen lines into wp-settings, when wp_debug_data is called. But an error_log from a plugin or theme should work?

Comment: @Rup,  the problem continues in a function in my child theme.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of educated guesses:

1. Is there a setting in Apache that circumvents your path in `WP_DEBUG_LOG`?
2. Did you check the Apache error logs for permission issues?

Comment: It's definitely not a permission issue because  I can write to the desired folder using error_log('hello', 3, '/desiredfolder/mylog.log') .  There's nothing interesting in the apache error log.  Also, using  ini_get('error_log') , I've confirmed that log is still set to the undesired location, not the location set with WP_DEBUG_LOG.  I've gotten that confirmation from a function called in my child theme, so (addressing the comment of @Rup), it doesn't seem to be a matter of delayed config of that setting.  Unless I have to delay even more.

Comment: Regarding an Apache setting, I checked /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and found nothing.